# Website Footer Text Not Aligning With The Top of The Footer

Tags: html, css, text, footer

I am making a website and I want a footer that has some basic information about our group(address, contact information, etc.) The actually method I am using to make the footer may be flawed (and please correct me if it is) but my main issue is text. I want the text titled "Questions, Comments, or Conserns?" to hug the top of the footer. I also want any additional text I add to the footer to do the same. I can not figure out how to do it. My code and a picture of what i am describing is below.
[This is the picture of what the footer looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9G4p.png).

HTML:

```
        <footer id="footer">
            <ul class="footer-text">
                <li class="footer-title">Address</li>
                <li>place holder</li>
                <li>place holder</li>
                <li>place holder</li>
                <li>place holder</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="footer-text">
                <li class="footer-title">Questions, Comments, or Conserns?</li>
                <li>place holder</li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    background:#F6F7F9;
    bottom:0;
    height:17%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

.footer-text {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footer-title {
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but it's spelled "Concerns".

Answer (score 0):

set display property to inline-grid, this will solve your issue but in your html need to more improvement, you have to use div element to design html page

```
.footer-text {
    display:inline-grid;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: I've only been coding HTML/CSS for about a week so I'm pretty nooby. None the less, thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align vertically top your ul elements using vertical-align: top; so the solution would be:

```
.footer-text {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/YaLWXL)